# Is there way to compare time values stored as string value in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column (time) in database with time stored as `varchar` in the format `hh.mm.ss` . I have a PHP string variable with time value stored in same format . I need to select all rows where time column values greater than variable time value.

I tried this query but it's not working

```
$timevar='15.26.00';
$sql="select name,id from device where time > '$timevar' ";
```

Is there any other way I can achieve this without modifying my table structure?

Comment: What's wrong with the approach you're using?

Comment: Why you not using DATETIME/DATE/TIMESTAMP/YEAR data types in your mysql database ???

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Answer (score 0):

If your column is a varchar just use replace function to get rid of dots: `replace(value, '.', '')`. You will get strings with integers, like : `152600` and those can be directly compared against each other.

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca8e4b/12/0

Schema:

```
Create table a (b varchar(10));

Insert into a Values ('16.00.00');
Insert into a Values ('17.00.00');
Insert into a Values ('16.01.00');
Insert into a Values ('15.59.00');
Insert into a Values ('16.00.01');
```

Query:

```
select * from a where replace(b, '.', '') > replace('16.00.00', '.', '');
```

a is table name so device in your case, a is column with times, so time in your case.

Result:

```
|        b |
|----------|
| 17.00.00 |
| 16.01.00 |
| 16.00.01 |
```

Your query would look something like this:

```
$timevar='15.26.00';
$sql="select name,id from device where replace(time, '.', '') > replace('$timevar', '.', '');";
```

When this starts working for you fix sql injection issues as mentioned in comments. Also even better solution would be to migrate to time column type.